# how can use window.location in echo using php code

Tags: php

I need help for using `window.location=` in `echo` with `PHP`. Here is my code:

```
echo
    '<div class="adsa">
         <div class="adimg125" style="'.$stylea.'">
            <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); window.location='.$url.'" class="check" style="'.$check.'">Check Monitors</div>
         </div>
    </div>';
```

My data showing fine but link not working mean its not show in ' ' for opening link. Here is my data which is displayed

```
<div class="check" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); window.location=/index.php?key=perfectdeposit.biz" style="background: #767a81 none repeat scroll 0 0; color: white; cursor: pointer; display: none; font-size: 13px; padding: 2px 0 3px; position: relative; text-align: center; top: -132px; width: 117px; margin-left: 38px">Check Monitors</div>
```

You can see here is not show ' '  in that line

```
window.location=/index.php?key=perfectdeposit.biz
```

it's need to show like this

```
window.location='/index.php?key=perfectdeposit.biz'
```

Comment: You are missing quote after `window.location`, it should be like `window.location="'.$url.'" class="check"`

Comment: yeah you are right but when i use link you then its showing same as i post above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to escape those characters in PHP. Maybe something like this?

```
echo'<div class="adsa"><div class="adimg125" style="'.$stylea.'">
            <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); window.location=\''.$url.'\'" class="check" style="'.$check.'">Check Monitors</div>
            </div></div>';
```

Notice the `\` near the `window.location`.

Here is the output:

```
$stylea = 'something';
$url = 'http://google.com';
$check = 'test';

<div class="adsa"><div class="adimg125" style="something">
        <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); window.location='http://google.com'" class="check" style="test">Check Monitors</div>
        </div></div>
```

Comment: @JerryStone Good deal! Want to mark it as the answer so others will know if they stumble upon the same question? ;)

Comment: am new and don't know how can mark. PLEASE do it  if you can

Comment: @JerryStone Only the person asking the question can mark the answer. You should see a checkmark near the answer - just click that to mark the answer. Look here: https://d2ppvlu71ri8gs.cloudfront.net/items/2r2Q0s422w3C2x0p1M1z/%5Bac8d0430bfa4e8e91dab2e9413b0ad8f%5D_Screen+Shot+2017-05-21+at+8.26.13+AM.png

Comment: i have do it Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I normally use [heredoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to avoid quote errors, i.e.:

```
echo <<< EOF
<div class="adsa"><div class="adimg125" style="$stylea">
    <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); window.location='$url' class="check" style="$check">Check Monitors</div>
</div>
EOF;
```

---

Output:

```
<div class="adsa"><div class="adimg125" style="some_style">
    <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); window.location='/index.php?key=perfectdeposit.biz' class="check" style="something">Check Monitors</div>
</div>
```

---

[PHP Demo](https://eval.in/802239)

Comment: its not working when i use this then my browser show me blank page error

Comment: add a blank line after `EOF;` . Also add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?